# ¿Cómo puedo restar 2 fechas y esta me de el resultado en días?

Tags: java, string, date

**//Suponiendo que tengo 2 variables tipo String que me almacenan las fechas:**

`String fechaInicio = "19-01-2019";`
`String fechaFinal = "20-10-2019";`

Comment: Hola Hamset, podrías compartir algún bloque de código que ya tengas hecho?, es para poder ayudarte a partir de algo. Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Mario, tengo este código que es para sumar dias a la fecha actual (esta me genera la fechaFinal): public static String Adddates(int Dias) {
        // Get today's date
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(); Calendar cldr;
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        cldr = (Calendar) date.clone();
        cldr.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, + Dias);
     
     return dateformatter.format(cldr.getTime());
    }
Este código me da mi fechaFinal y la fechaInicial es la del sistema.¿Cómo puedo restarlas para que me de la diferencia en dias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no te sera muy factible la resta, prueba con esto, para sustituirlo, y te faltaría aquí convertir el String en fecha

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar(2001, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        GregorianCalendar gc1=new GregorianCalendar(2002, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

        int days=0;

        while (!gc.equals(gc1)) {

            gc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
            days++;
        }

        System.out.println(days);
    }
```

Comment: Excelente dinki, probaré tu código. ¡Muchas gracias por tu aporte amigo!